# Can't understand the syntax & priority

Tags: c++, c, syntax, output

I have this code - http://ideone.com/wslBnj

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int array[2][3] = {5,10,15,20,25,30};
    int (*ptr)[2][3] = &array; // line 1
    printf("%d\n",***ptr);
    printf("%d\n",*(*ptr)[1]);// line 2
    printf("%d\n",(*ptr)[1][2]);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand the LHS(left hand side) syntax at 'line 1'. What does it mean (in words)?

I don't understand the priority given in 'line 2'. I mean, the output could be for `(*(*ptr))[1]` this grouping, but it was for this `*((*ptr)[1])`. Why is that?

Can someone explain both the doubts in detail? I couldn't understand the search terms to search for this question on internet. That's why I am asking it directly here.

Comment: Might be helpful, at least for part of the doubts: http://cdecl.org/

Comment: this line: int array[2][3] = {5,10,15,20,25,30}; is poorly written, as the row/column results is implementation defined.  rather use: int array[2][3] = {{5,10,15},{20,25,30}};

Answer (score 3):

> I don't understand the LHS(left hand side) syntax at 'line 1'. What
>   does it mean (in words)?

In C, declarations follow use.. It means that `(*ptr)[2][3]` is of type `int` (well, technically, [2][3] would be out of bounds, but you get the point). Anyway, this implies that `(*ptr)` is a multi-dimensional array of ints - namely, a 2x3 array of ints. Therefore, `ptr` is a pointer to an array[2][3] of ints.

> I don't understand the priority given in 'line 2'. I mean, the output
>   could be for (*(*ptr))[1] this grouping, but it was for this
>   *((*ptr)[1]). Why is that?

Indexing has higher priority than dereferencing. Thus, `*(*ptr)[1]` is equivalent to `*((*ptr)[1])`, and in this case it is equivalent to `(*ptr)[1][0]`, since `(*ptr)[1]` is an array of 3 ints.

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
int (*ptr)[2][3] = &array; // line 1
```

declares a pointer `( *ptr )` to an object of type int[2][3] That is it is a pointer to two dimensional array of type int[2][3]

If you would not use parentheses

```
int * ptr[2][3];
```

then the declaration would mean a two dimensional array of pointers of type `int *`

In line #2 expression

```
*(*ptr)[1]
```

is evaluated in the following order.

```
1. ( *ptr )
```

As ptr is declared as an pointer to a two dimemsional array then dereferencing the pointer will give the object pointed to by the pointer. So ( *ptr ) means array

```
int array[2][3]

2. ( *ptr )[1]
```

is the reference to the second row of the array

and at last in this expression

```
3. *( *ptr )[1]
```

the array ( *ptr )[1] that is the second row of the array "array" is converted to pointer to its first element and this pointer is dereferenced. So as result `*( *ptr )[1]`the first element of the second row of array "array" that is you will get 20.

Operator * that is an unary operator has lower priority than operator [] and is evaluated right to left.

From the C++ Standard

> 5.3 Unary expressions
>   1 Expressions with unary operators group right-to-left.

Thus if you will write for your array "array" expression

```
**array
```

then at first there is evaluated subexpression `*array` that will yield the reference to the first row of the array and then `*( *array )` will yield the first element of the first row.

Answer (score 1):

int (*ptr)[2][3] could also mean a pointer to the first [2][3] matrix in a 3d array, for example:

```
    int array[2][2][3] = {{{4,8,12},{8,16,24}},{{5,10,15},{20,25,30}}};
    int (*ptr)[2][3] = array;  // note &array is not used here
```